# Sequelize - double joining table on two IDs

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

If I have a "Users" table and a "Followings" table ("Followings" has UserId and FollowedId, both refer to users on the "Users" table)

"Followings" is basically when one user "follows" another user

How do I set up the associations so that when I use the Followings Model to query and include the Users model, it will include nested info for BOTH columns?

Example:

```
Users
| id | name | email | etc |

Followings
| id | UserId | FollowedId |
```

UserId and FollowedId are both assciated to users on "Users" table.

I tried this:

```
User.hasMany(Following);
Following.belongsTo(User, {foreignKey: 'FollowedId'});
Following.belongsTo(User, {foreignKey: 'UserId'});
```

But when I use:

```
Followings.find({
  include: User
})
```

It will only nest information on the UserId and not the FollowedID user.

Please ask questions if this is confusing, thanks!

EDIT: using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think if you give a name to the `belongsTo` you can specify the relationship in your include. So something like:

```
User.hasMany(Following);
Following.belongsTo(User, {foreignKey: 'FollowedId', as: 'Followee'});
Following.belongsTo(User, {foreignKey: 'UserId', as: 'User'});
```

With the include like:

```
Followings.find({
  include: [
    { model: User, as: 'Followee' },
    { model: User, as: 'User' },
  ]
})
```